# No query results for model [App\Project] in Laravel 5.2 how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hi I need pass Project Model id as project_id to My Task Model table. this is My TaskController

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));

    // Find the project with the given id
    $project = Project::findOrFail($request->get('project_id'));

    // This will set the project_id on task and save it
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
}
```

this is My form action route regarding to store task data in projects folder blade file is show.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('tasks.store') }}">
```

this is Task Model

```
class Task extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['task_name', 'body', 'assign','priority','duedate','project_id'];

public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }
public function projects()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }
```

this is Project Model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['project_name','project_notes','project_status','color','group'];
    //

    public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

but I got this error massage here

> No query results for model [App\Project].

how can i fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model assumes your primary key is id. if you have different primary key in that case please define it in your model.

protected $primarykey = "project_id"; // or whatever it is

2nd - i think you should use your foreign key name in 2nd parameter of relationship functions.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Task','foregin_key_name');
return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','foreign_key_name');
```